# Random sample using hive

Tags: hive

I'm trying to get a 5% random sample from a huge table.

```
create table database.five_percent_table as select * from (select distinct id from database.customer_list) where rand() <= 0.05 and month = 06;
```

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 3:0
>   cannot recognize input near 'where' 'rand' '(' in subquery source

I couldn't figure out the reason. Any help here is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: after WHERE You must specify [column_name]

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE database.five_percent_table AS
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT distinct id
    FROM database.customer_list
) alias
WHERE rand() <= 0.05 AND month = 06;
```

From the docs:

> Hive supports subqueries only in the FROM clause (through Hive 0.12).
>   The subquery has to be given a name because every table in a FROM
>   clause must have a name. Columns in the subquery select list must have
>   unique names. The columns in the subquery select list are available in
>   the outer query just like columns of a table. The subquery can also be
>   a query expression with UNION. Hive supports arbitrary levels of
>   subqueries.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries